# Why can't we make a good comparison? ruby-ffi call golang(so files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, go

I'm calling shared files created by Golang from ruby-ffi.
However, when I run Golang alone, the process works, but when I run it via ruby-ffi, the comparison doesn't work.

```
package main

import (
  "C"
  "fmt"
)

//export zen_roma_to_han_roma
func zen_roma_to_han_roma(s string) string {
  if s=="test" {
    return "10"
  }
  return s
}

func main(){
  fmt.Println(zen_roma_to_han_roma("test"))
}
```

```
$ go run replace.go                                                                                                                                                               
10
```

Here's an example of what can go wrong.
First, create a go build and load it.

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o replace.so replace.go
```

```
module Sample
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'replace.so'

  attach_function :zen_roma_to_han_roma, [:string], :string
end
```

```
[5] pry(main)> Sample.zen_roma_to_han_roma("test")
=> "test
```

I don't know the cause of this and I need your help.
Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Golang programmer but still here is a quote from [the FFI gem documentation](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Types)

> `:string` should be considered to be `const char *` and the Ruby string must not be changed as long as it’s accessed by the library. If the string buffer shall be modified from C or Ruby side, use `:pointer` and `FFI::MemoryPointer` instead.

So you should pass `*C.char` as an argument and return a value of the same type instead of `string`.

```golang
package main

import (
  "C"
  "fmt"
)

//export zen_roma_to_han_roma
func zen_roma_to_han_roma(s *C.char) *C.char {
  test_string := C.GoString(s)
  if test_string == "test" {
    return C.CString("10")
  }
  return s
}

func main() {
   fmt.Println(C.GoString(zen_roma_to_han_roma(C.CString("test"))))
}
```